# Looking for birth record of Catherine Jones in Llanfynydd, circa 1882

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, wales, birthplace, carmarthenshire

I'm looking for the above record of a birth of Catherine Jones, said to have been born around 1882 in Llanfynydd, which could be any number of places in Wales. She married my great-great grandfather John James Cowin, and they had a family in the Wirral Peninsula (Birkenhead, Hoylake and West Kirby).

Catherine gave birth to my Great grandfather Walter Cowin in 1910, she also had children John James Jr, Elsie, William Robert, and Katherine. She was married to John James Cowin.

John James Cowin and Catherine married in 1903. On the 1911 census, in Hoylake, her birth place is listed as Llanfynydd, Webs (a misreading of Wales). The census record shown in [findmypast's transcription](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=gbc%2F1911%2Frg14%2F21950%2F0145%2F1&fulfillmentTypeKey=1014) is:

> ```
> Census reference  RG14PN21950 RG78PN1307 RD451 SD4 ED9 SN73 
> RG78 code number 
> Piece number  21950
> ```

Comment: The link to your family tree isn't working for me. In any case I think it would be useful if you could list all the facts you know about Catherine's birth - that is, what do each of the censuses, marriage, death records, etc say about her age/date of birth/place of birth. Unfortunately I don't think you could have chosen a more difficult surname to research in Wales than Jones! ;)

Comment: @HarryVervet added more info, currently looking for a piece somewhere that I've misplaced too; I'll edit as soon as I find it.

Comment: The 1911 census you linked to has a calculated birth year of 1882. What other sources do you have for her birth, and which ones indicated she was born around 1878?

Comment: @JanMurphy I'm looking about for a source I had a hold of. I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: @JanMurphy I think I've lost the source, sorry. Schoolboy error not properly recording sources. Hope you can still help and I've also set up another question to recover my sources

Comment: Do you have Catherine's father's name from her marriage certificate?

Comment: Reviewing the information you've collected so far is part of the research process.  It can be helpful to construct a timeline and note where each bit of information came from.  When you review all your sources as a group, it's easier to spot possible problems like conflicting information.  Don't be afraid to keep a journal and write down your thoughts about the problem in really nitpicky detail, like how you arrived at the estimate for someone's birth year. It's much easier to leave a problem and come back to it later when you have notes that say where you left off.

Comment: @sempaiscuba no I do not, just that both married. I will be buying a PDF of the certificate and go from there.

Comment: Ancestry.co.uk has an Andrews Newspaper Index [card](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/interactive/1897/31031_A100097-00956?pid=110273) for Catherine Jones' marriage to John James Cowin in Chester. It gives her address as Brook St, Chester and her father as Robert Jones, a farm labourer. One witness is hard to read (Thos Ewin?), the other was Emily Jones.

Comment: That leads to an interesting 1891 census entry in Llanfynydd ([FMP version](https://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=gbc%2f1891%2f0019642010)) for Robert Jones' family, including Catherine and a sister Emily. Worth a look. Catherine's birthplace appears to be "Gwillt, Flintshire", which doesn't seem to exist, so it may be an abbreviation or the name of a local farm etc.

Comment: @AndyW that's interesting. I'll have to give that a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to check is the marriage certificate for Catherine and John James Cowin (From [FreeBMD](https://www.freebmd.org.uk/cgi/search.pl): Q3 (Sept) 1903; Chester; Vol 8a; Page 843).

The marriage record should give you the name of Catherine's father, it may give you her age (sometimes it will just show "full"), and it will show her address at the time of the marriage. (Make a note of the names of the witnesses too. They might be relatives!)

Next, it's probably worth checking the address you find on the marriage certificate in the 1901 census, just in case she was living there then. If she was, that will give you an age and a birthplace - hopefully confirming the info you have from the 1911 census. It may even give you more family members.

Llanfynydd was in the registration district of ***Llandilofawr*** from 1837 to 1935.

FreeBMD shows just five Catherine Jones registered in Llandilofawr between 1880 and 1884. In the worst-case scenario, you could just get all the certificates and check the names of the fathers. However, this is not a cheap option - even with the new [GRO PDF certificate](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/login.asp) service.

Comment: There's also a Llanfynydd in Flintshire, which is nearer to Chester. It could be that one too.

Comment: I definitely won't be able to buy all of those certificates. Not a valid option unfortunately. Saying that, I do have a strong indication from census records that she was born in 1882

Comment: @Charlie That is also true, although I did find a Kate Jones working as a servant in Chester in the [1901 census](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:XS6F-WHK), with a birthplace listed as Llanfynydd, Carmarthenshire. First things first, though. Check the details on the marriage certificate. :)

Comment: How should I go about doing that? Should I order a physical copy from the GRO? I live in Chester so can visit the Chester record office if they will have it

Comment: The current GRO PDF Pilot is for birth and death certificates only, not for marriage certificates. Take a look at the questions https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12865/1006 and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4245/1006 for ideas on finding out where the marriages took place before you order the certificates.